# String set in constructor is nullable in the returned object

Tags: kotlin

I have the following situation. My app uses API of Trakt Tv to get information about movies. There's no direct link to get the poster to the film and that's why I construct this link by myself:

```
"http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[apikey]&i=${movieTrack.movie?.movieId?.imdb!!}"
```

This line:

```
movieTrack.movie?.movieId?.imdb!!
```

is not null, but the whole return construction:

```
return Movie(
        name = movieTrack.movie?.name!!,
        year = movieTrack.movie?.year!!,
        movieId = movieTrack.movie?.movieId!!,
        watchers = movieTrack.watchersNumber,
        iconUrl = "http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[apikey]&i=${movieTrack.movie?.movieId?.imdb!!}"
)
```

returns an object, which has nullable icon url. So, I can't understand how such situation can happen. What's the matter?

Comment: "Nullable icon URL" doesnt mean that it is null, it means that it can be null.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable is not null. Nullable means, that the value CAN be null, which may lead to problems when you reference it in some place where null-values aren't allowed.

This is why you can declare stuff as "non-nullable", to assert that the value can never be null, and other variables are nullable, which means they can contain null.

So in conclusion:

Nullable: CAN be null. (Careful when doing certain things, might mess things up, but standard for most things)

Non-Nullable: MUST NEVER be null. (But you have to invest some work to assert that it can't ever be null.)